# Unable to Unmerge Cells Using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in an Excel worksheet. Four of the columns have merged cells. I have to unmerge two columns ("A" and "D") and put data in the unmerged cells based on certain conditions. My attempt to unmerge specific column using following code did not unmerge the cells or return any error message

```
If sheet5.Range("A1", "A2783").MergeCells Then 
sheet5.Range("A1", "A2783").MergeCells.UnMerge
```

Then I tried this

```
If ActiveSheet.Cells.MergeCells Then 
sht.Cells.UnMerge
```

but that also did not unmerge the cells or return any error message.

Any pointers please?

Comment: `Columns("A:A").UnMerge` you can't just unmerge A & D

Comment: Thanks. That worked!

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the `MergeCells` property to `False`:

```
sheet5.Range("A1", "A2783").MergeCells = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UnMerge` method should be called on the `Range` object returned by the `MergeArea` property of a `Range` object.

Also,

> The MergeArea property only works on a single-cell range.
>   so write:

```
If sheet5.Range("A1").MergeCells Then 
sheet5.Range("A1").MergeArea.UnMerge
```

instead.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.unmerge